# Pythagoras Theorem Proof

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Is my logic correct below to prove the [Pythagoras Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)? Thanks.

Area Rectangle **R**
\begin{align*}
R &= WL\\
  &=(2a+b)(2b+a)\\
  &=4ab+2a^2+2b^2+ab\\
  &=5ab+2a^2+2b^2
\end{align*}

Total Area Yellow Triangles **T**
\begin{align*}
T &= 10(\frac{ab}{2})\\
&=5ab
\end{align*}

Calculate Area $c^2$

\begin{align*}
c^2 &= R-T-a^2-b^2 \\
   &=5ab+2a^2+2b^2-5ab-a^2-b^2\\
   &=a^2+b^2
\end{align*}
∎

[image: lattice]

**Proof by rearrangement**

[image: gerryPythag]

Comment: See also [Bhaskara's proof](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~demo5337/Group3/Bhaskara.html).

Comment: Bhaskara Proof is from https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/ Proof #3
Is my proof new or already discovered? Thanks!

Comment: For something as worked over as the Pythagorean Theorem, assume it's already discovered.  A very extensive literature search would be needed to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is correct provided you have shown that all yellow triangles are congruent.

Comment: SAS (side-angle-side) congruency is sufficient. They each have two smaller sides $a$ and $b$ and one included right angle.

Comment: Yes ofcourse! It is neat. +1 For more visual proofs like this, also see https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/

Comment: Wow...thanks for verifying cosmo5!

Comment: Added a "Proof by rearrangement" above. I hope that's correct too? Thanks.

Comment: It morphs $c^2$ into another shape R, but keeps the same area. After rearranging, R is equal to $a^2+b^2$ which has area $c^2$, so $c^2=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Oh very nice! Yes this would count as another proof!

Comment: Thanks! It's a non-algebraic proof. Got the idea from this simple animation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Proofs_by_dissection_and_rearrangement