# What constitutes a unique Pythagoras Theorem Proof?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

For example, John Molokach listed a nice proof #87 here:

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Pyth3Trapezoids.shtml

[image]

and I recently discovered a very similar method:

[Pythagoras Theorem Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927974/pythagoras-theorem-proof)

[image]

As you can see, John's proof uses these area methods:

- Square
- Triangle
- **Trapezoid**

My proof uses:

- Square
- Triangle

Seeing as they're similar in structure, could these proofs be considered "unique"?

Feels like someone could take any proof, add some irrelevant steps, then Voilà, another proof.

For example, both proofs above utilize concepts from another
[proof #9](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/)

[image: Proof #9]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'd say this was purely a matter of opinion.  Maybe someone could defend a distinction between, say, the proofs that work via rearrangements, and those that work by similarity, and so on, but that would still leave many ambiguous cases.

Comment: I'll take this as his proof is trapezoidal focused, hence the title "Pythagorean Theorem: An Algebraic Proof with Three Trapezoids" whereas mine is more triangle centric. In my opinion, using trapezoids introduces another layer of area computation complexity. Meh.